# Fork of Old magento/magento2-samples Modules

Tags: magento2, module, github

Magento's GitHub account used to have a project at

https://github.com/magento/magento/magento2-samples

This repository contained around 20 examples of *How to Build* a Magento 2 module.  However, [this project's been deleted because -- reasons](https://github.com/magento/devdocs/issues/1133)?

While some of practices in these modules have been abandoned, and not all the modules ran, this was still an important resource, both historic and practical, for developers learning and working with Magento 2.

Does anyone know if there's any public forks of the repository available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've forked the most recent one I could find - https://github.com/BenSpace48/magento2-samples

### Update

They're back with an out of date disclaimer - https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples